# Image size reduction in iOS Mail

Tags: iphone, html, css, ios, html-email

I'm creating an HTML mail template for an app, and the template includes a 440px wide image.

When i look at it on my iphone, it goes beyond the width of the screen. I've seen plenty of times when iOS Mail shrinks the size of the email to fit everything in (for instance, emails from Apple).

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?  The image CSS and it's container CSS is:

```
.photo {
    width: 400px;
    height: 460px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.photo img.main-photo {
    max-width: 400px;
}
.photo div.caption {
    width: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    font-family: 'Indie Flower';
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

and the actual HTML is

```
<div class="photo">
    <img src="{{ photo.images.standard_resolution.url }}" class="main-photo" />
    <div class="caption">
        {{ photo.caption.text }}
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:** Here is an example of how it looks.  I dont want it to stretch beyond the screen

[image]

Comment: Do you see this issue when editing the mail or when viewing the received mail in the iOS Mail app?

Comment: viewing the received mail in the iOS Mail app

Comment: Just updated the initial post above with how it looks

Comment: Have you tried making the image smaller? :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to delete the width and only use max-width. I think that would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`400px` is too wide, the non-retina iPhone's are `320px` wide. If Mail is like Mobile Safari, it'll even treat it the iPhone 4 as `320px` wide. Have you tried smaller sizes?